# Not able to use getter method of Interface

Tags: java, interface

I have written below code, just to play with interface, Would you
please tell where I have gone wrong here?

This is my interface:

```
package com.home.intetest;

public interface IFoo {

    public abstract String doWork(String str) throws Exception;

}
```

This is where I have implemented,

```
package com.home.intetest;

public class FooImpl implements IFoo {

    @Override
    public String doWork(String str) throws Exception {

        if(str !=null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Wrongggg");
        }

        return str;
    }

}
```

Now I am trying to call them from main, using getter method, its giving me error,in line where I am using getiFoo method

```
package com.home.intetest;


public class TestMain {

    private IFoo iFoo;

    public IFoo getiFoo() {
        return iFoo;
    }

    public void setiFoo(IFoo iFoo) {
        this.iFoo = iFoo;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Work method";
        callWorkMethod(str);
    }

    private static void callWorkMethod(String str) {

        String s = getiFoo().doWork(str);

    }

}
```

Comment: `getiFoo()` is not static so you cannot call it from a static context.

Comment: okay, Got it, I changed it, to private static IFoo iFoo; Now its giving me null pointer exception, when running it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1

The line

```
getiFoo().doWork(str);
```

can not be called, you need a instance of TestMail first! So *boot-up* your Application like this:

```
new TestMain().getiFoo().doWork(str);
```

### 2

The error you recieve is a `NullPointerException` now because `iFoo` is always `null`.

Create a instance in the getter using the default constructor like this:

```
public IFoo getiFoo() {
    if (iFoo == null) {
       iFoo = new FooImpl();
    }
    return iFoo;
}
```

Or inside the declaration like this:

```
private IFoo iFoo = new FooImpl();
```

Comment: I got my mistake , I have not instantiate it , Thanks Much !!